# angularjs dynamic model in template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to create dynamic inputs, textareas..etc. So for each input type I have a separate  template. So a text field template could look like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/input.html">
    <input type="text" ng-model="model" />
</script>
```

and what I am trying to achieve is something like this:

```
<div ng-include="" src="'/input.html'" ng-init="model = var1"></div>
<div ng-include="" src="'/input.html'" ng-init="model = var2"></div>
```

so I can create text fields with the same template and have a different model for each one. That works actually and gets the data passed, but if I type something in the text field it doesn't get applied to the scope variable.

Here's a fiddle to illustrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/uAm99/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to implement this feature in "angular directive way". It can empower the HTML tag, such as reusable template (just mentioned in your implementation). Here is a simple example:

HTML

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <custom-input data="var1"></custom-input>
    <custom-input data="var2"></custom-input>
    {{var1}}
    {{var2}}
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module("myApp",[])
.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
  $scope.var1 = "foo";
  $scope.var2 = "bar";
})
.directive("customInput",function(){
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    scope: {
        data:"="
    },
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="data" />'
  };
});
```

And this is a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ST7sp/)

Hope it helpful.

Comment: Yes mister you are perfectly correct about this solution! You made my day, thanks so much!